# Mongoose error for a schema model declaration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When I was testing the model I got this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(mongoose#Document#scope)')

I am making an e-commerce API and other schemas and models are working fine but this model is throwing an error. And also there is no reserved "Product" in mongoose then why this error is occuring

Here's my product model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const mongoosePaginate = require("mongoose-paginate-v2");
var aggregatePaginate = require("mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2");


const Product = new mongoose.Schema({
    productId:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true,"Please add a product ID"],
        trim:true,
        unique:true,
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"Please add a description"],
        trim:true,
    },
    catId:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Category",
        required:[true,"Please add a category ID"],
    },
    subCatId:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"SubCategory",
        required:[true,"Please add a subcategory ID"],
    },
    brandId:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Brand",
        required:[true,"Please add a brand ID"],
    },
    unit:{
        type:String, // Pcs, Kg, Ltr, etc.
        required:[true,"Please add a unit"],
        trim:true,
    },
    purchaseQuantity: {
        min: {
          type: Number,
          default: 1,
        },
        max: {
          type: Number,
        },
      },
    refundable:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false,
    },
    taxId:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Tax",
        default:null,
    },
    collectionId:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Collections",
        default:null,
    },
    live:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false,
    },
    hsnCode:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"Please add a HSN code"],
        trim:true,
    },
    sellerId:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Seller",
        required:[true,"Please add a seller ID"],
    },
    sellerUserId:{
        type:Number,
        ref:"Seller",
        required:[true,"Please add a seller user ID"],
    },
    targetGender:{
        type:String,
        enum:['male','female','unisex'],
        required:[true,"Please add a target gender"],
        trim:true,
    },
    productSpecifications:{
        type:Array,
        required:[true,"Please add a product specification"],
        trim:true,
    },
    ageGroup:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"Please add an age group"],
        trim:true,
    },
    careInstructions:{
        type:String,
        required:[true,"Please add care instructions"],
        trim:true,
    },
},{timestamps:true,toJSON: { virtuals: true }, toObject: { virtuals: true } });

Product.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
Product.plugin(aggregatePaginate);


Product.virtual("category", {
    ref: "Category",
    localField: "catId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    justOne: true,
});

Product.virtual("subcategory", {
    ref: "SubCategory",
    localField: "subCatId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    justOne: true,
});

Product.virtual("brand", {
    ref: "Brand",
    localField: "brandId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    justOne: true,
});

Product.virtual("tax", {
    ref: "Tax",
    localField: "taxId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    justOne: true,
});

Product.virtual("collection", {
    ref: "Collections",
    localField: "collectionId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    justOne: true,
});

Product.virtual("seller", {
    ref: "Seller",
    localField: "sellerId",
    foreignField: "_id",
    justOne: true,

});

Product.virtual("variants", {
    ref: "Variant",
    localField: "productId",
    foreignField: "productId",
    justOne: false,
});




Product.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
Product.plugin(aggregatePaginate);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", Product);
```

I am getting error on this line :
`module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", Product);`

Error stack:

```
D:\BackendProjects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\document\compile.js:205
        this.$set.call(this.$__[scopeSymbol] || this, path, v);
                               ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Symbol(mongoose#Document#scope)')
    at Model.set [as collection] (D:\BackendProjects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\document\compile.js:205:32)
    at Function.compile (D:\BackendProjects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4733:30)
    at Mongoose._model (D:\BackendProjects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:620:27)
    at Mongoose.model (D:\BackendProjects\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:579:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\BackendProjects\src\models\Product Management\productModel.js:182:27) 
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Tech stack: Nodejs express Mongodb

I was trying to use my model for my controllers and routers and have no clue why this error occurs. I want to use the model in my controllers and router without changing the model name "Product"

Answer (score 0):

The Error occurred due to the usage of the `Collections` model and I renamed it as `ProductCollections` since I was using a ref there for `Collections` in collectionId field it was throwing an error in the `Product` Model and now changing it to the `ProductCollections` solved the error as the collection is a reserved word for mongoose schema [Reference to doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#Schema.reserved)